# I can not access phpmyadmin after updating PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 on CentOS

Tags: php, linux, apache, phpmyadmin

I updated phpadmin, it then gave error saying it needs latest version of PHP 5.5.

So i tried to update the PHP using this method:
http://anandarajpandey.com/2014/04/21/virtualmin-upgrate-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-php-5-5-or-higher-version-from-yum/

Didnt work due to:

```
php55w-common-5.5.29-1.w5.i386 from webtatic-el5 has depsolving problems
--> php55w-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php55w-common conflicts with php-common
```

So i removed php-common using this:

```
yum -y remove php-common
```

Then I installed php 5.5 using:

```
yum -y install php55w php55w-opcache php55w-common php55w-mysql php55w-mbstring php55w-cli php55w-gd php55w-pdo php55w-mcrypt
```

Then i checked php version it worked and was latest version.  but i noticed that when removing php it also removed and renamed some conf files one of them being "/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf"

I now get this error: (for http://198.154.62.131/phpMyAdmin/ )

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin/ on this server.
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at 198.154.62.131 Port 80
```

/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin "/usr/share/phpMyAdmin"

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.4
<RequireAny>
#Require ip 127.0.0.1
#Require ip ::1
Require all granted
</RequireAny>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.2
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
# Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from All
# Allow from 127.0.0.1
# Allow from ::1
</IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.4
Require local
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
# Apache 2.2
Order Deny,Allow
#Deny from All
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from 198.154.62.131
</IfModule>
</Directory>
```

/var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
[Mon Oct 12 21:11:24 2015] [error] [client 193.109.196.106] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/
```

I am using webmin, CentOS Linux 5.11

any ideas how to bet phpmyadmin back?

Comment: install phpMyAdmin with yum again? remove php-common probably also removed phpMyAdmin, when you installed it with the package managment system

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like the conf file was ok its just that some file/s was removed or changed in the usr/share/phpMyAdmin folder.

I renamed /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf.rpmsave back to phpMyAdmin.conf

I then did the following and it now works!
cd /usr/share
wget http://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.5.0.2/phpMyAdmin-4.5.0.2-all-languages.zip
unzip phpMyAdmin-4.5.0.2-all-languages.zip

Opened File manager, renamed phpMyAdmin to phpMyAdminOld. Deleted the downloaded zip file. Renamed phpMyAdmin-4.5.0.2-all-languages to phpMyAdmin.  Then copied the config.inc.php from phpMyAdminOld to phpMyAdmin  folder.  restarted apache. then it worked.

But now i get this error:

```
Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.67 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.28. This may cause unpredictable behavior.
```